# How does the government benefit from having people put their money into stocks instead of savings account?

Tags: japan, finance

> Roughly 20 years after the Japanese government first put up the banner
> of "from savings to investments," young people are showing a keen
> interest in investments, probably out of concern for their
> post-retirement funds. Deep-rooted wariness about investment losses,
> however, remains an impediment to a greater embrace of risk assets.
>
> The focus will be on whether the government initiative can inspire the
> largely conservative public to pivot away from bank deposits.
>
> "With this year as the first year of my 'asset income doubling plan,'
> we will promote, boldly and fundamentally, the shift from savings to
> investments," Prime Minister Fumio Kishida said in a video message at
> an event held by the Japan Securities Dealers Association (JSDA) and
> other organizations in February.

https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2023/04/25/business/economy-business/savings-to-investments-japan/

How does the government benefit from having people put their money into stocks instead of savings account? The government is trying to encourage people from investing their money into stocks, and giving them ample incentives, but does the benefits outweigh the costs? How does it benefit the government when the government can use the savings that finance their bonds and the government itself can invest into Japanese stocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does the government benefit from having people put their money into stocks instead of savings account?

It more directly stimulates the economy if the population is investing in companies more directly. Money parked in a savings account is eventually invested by banks, but that's a more indirect process.

> does the benefits outweigh the costs?

There's no simple answer to this, it [depends](https://www.cnbc.com/select/saving-vs-investing/) how much savings we're talking about and potential need for liquidity. There's surely more risk passed on to the [direct] investor, but there also potentially higher returns etc.

Comment: Why would direct stimulus (by amateur individual investors) be any more stimulating to the economy than indirect stimulus (by professional bankers)?

Comment: @Steve: because amusingly banks are more limited by laws/regulations in how they can risk their [customers'] money.

Comment: @Fizz "it depends how much savings we're talking about and potential need for liquidity" Japanese households have historically been extremely conservative, investing money mostly in postal accounts and if not there in very conservative, low risk investments. While the lack of clarity in the general case is a hard call, almost no developed country in the world is more biased towards savings accounts v. other investments than Japan, so it almost surely makes sense there to encourage alternatives.

Comment: @Steve one of the problems with indirect investment through banks (a highly concentrated industry in Japan with postal savings being dominant) is that you lose the wisdom of crowds. Also, that indirect investment is constrained more tightly in what it can do with the funds while insuring guaranteed savings account security. The indirect investors aren't sufficiently loss tolerant to maximize risk adjusted returns, so investments are made disproportionately in less risk than optimal opportunities for investment, thus slowing growth in a country with growth rate issues already.

Comment: @ohwilleke, surely the whole point of professional banking is to maximise risk-adjusted returns, and guarantee such a return by distributing profits and losses as widely as possible? Obviously an individual investor risks wipeout when investing in high-risk, high-return ways, even through the average return is high, but the bank doesn't because it is capable of averaging across many opportunities invested at different times. If the bank still risks wipeout, then the average return for individuals cannot in fact be positive - it is merely a game of redistribution, like monopoly. (1/2)

Comment: In other words, individual investing is better than bank investing primarily because the average returns to investors are negative, and the economy grows better basically by taxing the investor class - and they play for the same reason people play lotteries and casinos, despite negative average returns. Logically then, the answer for Japan would be to use the state to drive inflation up against savings by printing money, whilst allocating the proceeds to on-average negative-return economic investments. That would maximise growth. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve Investing postal deposits is regulated to be lower risk as is, to a lesser extent, investing savings deposits. It's like the S&L industry in the U.S. before it was reformed which was allowed to invest in secured real estate loans with big down payments only. The parameters of a bank that can't afford to take significant losses is quite different from the parameters of an investment bank whose customer-investors can take significant losses in exchange for the promise of better returns.

Comment: @Steve "individual investing is better than bank investing primarily because the average returns to investors are negative" The average return to stock investors has been positive and well in excess of risk free treasuries for every decade in U.S. history bar maybe one carefully chosen ten year period that is close to break even. This is not the economics of individual investing. Postal account investing and savings deposit investing are frequently generating net returns of less than inflation.

Comment: @ohwilleke, if stocks are high-return, then why don't banks invest in them? Indeed, is the structural problem precisely that returns on stocks are high because neither savings banks nor most individuals invest in them - and if they did, the rate of return would fall negative as more capital (than before) competed for the returns the stock market is capable of providing? There will be people in banking who understand these systemic reactions - it's why they don't invest saver's cash, because they know the average rate of return will turn negative if they supply more capital to the market

Comment: @Steve "why don't banks invest in them?" In the U.S., in order to invest in stocks you have to be an investment bank. Commercial banks aren't allowed to invest in stocks. Japan has similar regulations.

Comment: @ohwilleke, and the rationale I've given is quite possibly *why*, because it avoids private savings competing with investor capital (driving returns negative), and it avoids the *political problem* that would result if such competition were allowed to occur (which is a significant haircut for savers). The overt argument in the OP's quote is that more investment leads to more economic growth. The *implied* hypothesis is that such investment generates further returns, so it's win-win. (1/2)

Comment: I'm saying the actual reality is that such additional investments cheapen capital and cause returns to fall, and growth is promoted by increasing the amount of "no-return" failed investments in the economy. In other words, the economic tree is watered with the blood of investors who lose their capital. For the Japanese worker with no savings, this is all good, but for the Japanese capitalist making unearned returns on savings, the last thing they want is to follow this advice. It's akin to the state driving growth through taxation - taxation is no-return in the conventional sense. (2/2)

Comment: @ohwilleke, emphasising the same point again in different and even bolder words, the logic is that economic growth is promoted by making investments that return nothing to rentiers - by seizing the funds of rentiers, using them for investment, and giving nothing back to the rentier. That is indeed a proven method of growth, because it's exactly what the states of the capitalist world did in the post-war period - they taxed the rich (rather than borrowing from them), and pushed the extreme proceeds of that taxation into all kinds of economic investments and growth-helping public facilities.